# How to make a graph using matplotlib with equally spaced powers of 10?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have tried to plot a graph in which the value of points vary from 10^-8 to 10 with equal spacing but the points from 10^-8 to 0 appear stacked on each other.

eg.[I want a graph with y-axis like this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FQc3.jpg)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can show your code and sample data.

Comment: (x,y)-->(0.00050044059753417968750000000000000000000000000000,3.16227766016837952278706325159873813390731811523438),(0.00099921226501464843750000000000000000000000000000,0.00000000000046045734026605926965704388528401773070)

Comment: Thanks to the person who has marked my question  duplicate. I found how to make graph like I wanted. Thanks #ImportanceOfBeingErnest